# overall meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

The question as to what constitutes art is hardly a **contemporar**y one. Today, artists exist whose main goal seems only to subvert work that no longer **warrants the trite tag "cutting edge**". Once the **proverbial envelope is pushed even further**, the public inevitably **scratches its collective head**-or **furrows the collective brow**- thinking that this time the "artists" have gone too far. That very same admixture of contempt and conclusion, however, was not unknown in Michelangelo's day; only what was considered **blasphemous**, art-wise, in the 16th Century, would today be considered **tame.**

Can anyone explain what is the overall meaning of the sentence in relation to the bold parts?

Comment: Have you looked up the bolded words in a dictionary or Google?

Comment: Artists always try to be fresh and controversial, but what was controversial in the past is normal today.  It's sad that all those words can be condensed so easily and without losing much meaning.  That read like a college essay thesis.

Comment: [Contemporary (entry 1)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contemporary), [warrant (entry 2)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/warrant), [trite](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trite), [tag (entry 1, sense 5b)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tag), [cutting edge](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cutting%20edge), [to push the envelope](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/push%20the%20envelope). You do the rest of the research.